# Woocommerce Update Customer Password

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building a basic login / register page for my iOS app.

This app currently connects to my website via the Woocommerce API.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx
```

I can see all the customer's details and previous orders via the API but I can't seem to find where the customer's password is in the JSON package (or Woocommerce API documentation) so that the app can make changes to the customer's password.

Here's a sample of the JSON response:

```
{
        "id": 29327,
        "date_created": "2020-07-22T09:53:59",
        "date_created_gmt": "2020-07-21T23:53:59",
        "date_modified": "2020-07-27T08:51:33",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2020-07-26T22:51:33",
        "email": "xxxx",
        "first_name": "xxx",
        "last_name": "xxxx",
        "role": "customer",
        "username": "xxxx",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "xx",
            "last_name": "xxx",
            "company": "",
            "address_1": "xxx"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **[WooCommerce document](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#customers)** , we will see that the **Customer properties** contain the follow **Attributes** :

[image]

**However** , the `password` attribute is **write-only** type, ***therefore it will not show in the json response.***

Comment: That explains everything! Thank you so much!!